# Software KVM switch for Ubuntu, Windows, and Mac

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, keyboard

I have a multiple computer setup:

- 1 desktop, with the keyboard and mouse (Ubuntu)
- 2 laptops on the left and right (Win/Mac resp.)

I need an easy to configure software KVM switch so I can use my desktop keyboard and mouse while my laptops are on my desk. When I had Windows installed on my desktop PC, I used [Multiplicity](http://edgerunner.com/multiplicity), but that's out of the question now, it only supports Windows. I liked multiplicity because it had centralized audio, and a perfectly smooth user experience.

so here are the features I'm looking for,

- Software KVM compatible with Mac/Win/Ubuntu
- Centralized audio (optional, but preferred)

I would like an open source software alternative, but it's not absolutely necessary. Any recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/)

- Cross Platform Windows/OS-X/Linux
- GPL
- Price: Free *if you build it your self*, $10 pre-built basic edition lifetime licence, $29 pre-built pro edition lifetime licence *As at 11 Sept 2015*
- Share your clipboard (copy and paste) between your computers.
- Drag & Drop between Windows & Mac

*I have no affiliation with the Synergy project.*